# How getting the client id to specify for a Google BigQuery connector

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to use a Google BigQuery connector, to read GA data, specifying the User Authentication. Now how can I obtain the unique client id to pass to teh Google BigQuery connector?
Thanks

Comment: Please provide some more details on your question - what do you mean by 'BigQuery connector', are you working with the BQ UI or something else? Also, what do you mean by the 'user authentication'? Can you share what you have tried so far?

Comment: Hi, I'm creating a data pipeline in Azure Data Factory in order to get Google Analytics data for a company site. In the data pipeline, I've chosen the copy task; for this task I've chosen as a data source Google BigQuery and so I'm trying to use the related connector to get Google Analytics data. The Google BigQuery connector, for User Authentication type, requests to specify a refresh token; for generating it I need to obtain the client id and the client secret. I've tried to create an Oauth client ID (web app) inside the Google API console, but I don't know which is the right URLs to pass.

Comment: Please update your question with the details above, it should help you get more feedback.

Answer (score 1):

When configuring the BigQuery connector in Azure Data Factory, you must supply the client ID and client secret.  These can be obtained by creating new OAuth client credentials in the GCP console.

When creating the credentials, it will ask you for "Authorized redirect URIs".  You can enter anything you want there.  It just has to be in a valid URL format.  Be sure to make note of what you entered because you will have to use the *exact* same value when doing the OAuth2 dance.

For more details, you can read my article on how to set up User Authentication for BigQuery in ADF v2:  https://github.com/AnalyticJeremy/ADF_BigQuery

Comment: Hi Jeremy, I've read your article and applied it to ADF. I can create successfully a linked service having the Google BigQuery as a connector, but with it I'd like to read Google Analytics data. If possible, how can I accomplish a such task? Thanks